# WP Get Post ID To Which Current Tag Page (archive.php) Belongs To

Tags: wordpress

I just started my own business website with Wordpress. I am fairly new to WP.

I need to echo the 'Post Id' of post on archive.php (tag page) to which that tag belongs to.

Example: Post has an post id 1. When I create tag for post id 1, I need that post id to echo on that tag (archive) page.

Hope I made some sense.

I tried

```
`get_the_ID()`
'the_ID()'
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You are trying to echo the post id of the posts that display in the archive page?